# Debugging a recalcitrant eldoc function

Tags: debugging, eldoc

I'm using SLIME and common LISP (SBCL) for some weekend hacking.  I've just upgraded to emacs 26.1 on Mac OS X 10.13.5.  Now I've run into a problem with the setup where I'm suddenly getting:

```
error in process filter: progn: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 1), 2
```

I've turned on debug-on-error which provided me with

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 1) 2)

* eldoc-message("%s" #("(defun name lambda-list &body body)" 1 6 (face font-lock-keyword-face) 7 11 (face font-lock-function-name-face) 24 29 (face font-lock-type-face) 30 34 (face eldoc-highlight-function-argument)))
  (progn (eldoc-message "%s" (slime-autodoc--format doc multilinep)))
  (if (eldoc-display-message-p) (progn (eldoc-message "%s" (slime-autodoc--format doc multilinep))))
  (if (eq doc :not-available) nil (if cache-p (progn (slime-autodoc--cache-put context doc))) (if (eldoc-display-message-p) (progn (eldoc-message "%s" (slime-autodoc--format doc multilinep)))))
  (let* ((--cl-rest-- doc) (doc (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 2) (car-safe (prog1 --cl-rest-- (setq --cl-rest-- (cdr --cl-rest--)))) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--))))) (cache-p (car --cl-rest--))) (if (eq doc :not-available) nil (if cache-p (progn (slime-autodoc--cache-put context doc))) (if (eldoc-display-message-p) (progn (eldoc-message "%s" (slime-autodoc--format doc multilinep))))))
  slime-autodoc--async%(("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t))
  apply(slime-autodoc--async% (("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t)))
  (lambda (&rest more) (apply 'slime-autodoc--async% (append '(("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit) more)))(("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t))
  funcall((lambda (&rest more) (apply 'slime-autodoc--async% (append '(("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit) more))) ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t))
  (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))
  (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result)))
  (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (result (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))))
  (cond ((eql op-12 ':ok) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (result (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))))) ((eql op-12 ':abort) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (condition (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (message "Evaluation aborted on %s." condition))) (t (error "slime-dcase failed: %S" tmp-14)))
  (let* ((tmp-14 G11) (op-12 (car tmp-14)) (rand-13 (cdr tmp-14))) (cond ((eql op-12 ':ok) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (result (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))))) ((eql op-12 ':abort) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (condition (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (message "Evaluation aborted on %s." condition))) (t (error "slime-dcase failed: %S" tmp-14))))
  (closure ((--cl-buffer-- . --buffer--) (--cl-cont-- . --cont--) (package) (cont lambda (&rest more) (apply 'slime-autodoc--async% (append '(("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit) more))) (sexp swank:autodoc '("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) :print-right-margin 200) slime-default-connection slime-net-processes slime-buffer-connection slime-buffer-package slime-current-thread slime-dispatching-connection slime-buffer-connection t) (G15 G16 G11) (let* ((tmp-14 G11) (op-12 (car tmp-14)) (rand-13 (cdr tmp-14))) (cond ((eql op-12 ':ok) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (result (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))))) ((eql op-12 ':abort) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (condition (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (message "Evaluation aborted on %s." condition))) (t (error "slime-dcase failed: %S" tmp-14)))))(--buffer-- --cont-- (:ok ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t)))
  apply((closure ((--cl-buffer-- . --buffer--) (--cl-cont-- . --cont--) (package) (cont lambda (&rest more) (apply 'slime-autodoc--async% (append '(("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit) more))) (sexp swank:autodoc '("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) :print-right-margin 200) slime-default-connection slime-net-processes slime-buffer-connection slime-buffer-package slime-current-thread slime-dispatching-connection slime-buffer-connection t) (G15 G16 G11) (let* ((tmp-14 G11) (op-12 (car tmp-14)) (rand-13 (cdr tmp-14))) (cond ((eql op-12 ':ok) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (result (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))))) ((eql op-12 ':abort) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (condition (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (message "Evaluation aborted on %s." condition))) (t (error "slime-dcase failed: %S" tmp-14))))) --buffer-- --cont-- (:ok ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t)))
  (lambda (&rest --cl-rest--) (apply (function (closure ((--cl-buffer-- . --buffer--) (--cl-cont-- . --cont--) (package) (cont lambda (&rest more) (apply 'slime-autodoc--async% (append '(("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) truncate-sym-name-if-fit) more))) (sexp swank:autodoc '("defun" "equilateral-p" ("a" "b" "c") ("setq" "candidates" ("list" "a" "b" "c")) swank::%cursor-marker%) :print-right-margin 200) slime-default-connection slime-net-processes slime-buffer-connection slime-buffer-package slime-current-thread slime-dispatching-connection slime-buffer-connection t) (G15 G16 G11) (let* ((tmp-14 G11) (op-12 (car tmp-14)) (rand-13 (cdr tmp-14))) (cond ((eql op-12 ':ok) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (result (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (if (symbol-value G16) (progn (set-buffer (symbol-value G15)) (funcall (symbol-value G16) result))))) ((eql op-12 ':abort) (let* ((--cl-rest-- rand-13) (condition (if (= (length --cl-rest--) 1) (car --cl-rest--) (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list nil (length --cl-rest--)))))) (message "Evaluation aborted on %s." condition))) (t (error "slime-dcase failed: %S" tmp-14)))))) '--buffer-- '--cont-- --cl-rest--))((:ok ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t)))
  slime-dispatch-event((:return (:ok ("(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)" t)) 6) #<process SLIME Lisp>)
  slime-process-available-input(#<process SLIME Lisp>)
  slime-net-filter(#<process SLIME Lisp> "000045(:return (:ok (\"(defun name lambda-list &body ===> body <===)\" t)) 6)")
```

So my current belief is that eldoc is choking on the interpolated string being passed to the function eldoc-message.

What I'm not clear on is:

1. Am I barking up the wrong tree here? I'm concerned that the function isn't explicitly mentioning progn
2. Am I correct in thinking the # should be followed by a single quote mark to make it a lambda?

Comment: `eldoc-message` used to take any number of arguments, since Emacs 26, it takes 0 or 1 argument, however, you are supplying 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner way, where you don't have to run mismatched SLIME and SWANK versions (which is asking for trouble), is to override the relevant function in SLIME that calls eldoc-message. Elisp is still a LISP after all.

This overrides `slime-autodoc--async%` with the version found in SLIME 2.21, just add it your .emacs (or any file you load):

```
;; fix for slime <v2.21 in emacs 26 (eldoc-message now only takes 1 arg)
(when (version< slime-version "2.21")
  (defun slime-autodoc--async%-fixed (context multilinep doc)
    (cl-destructuring-bind (doc cache-p) doc
      (unless (eq doc :not-available)
        (when cache-p
          (slime-autodoc--cache-put context doc))
        ;; Now that we've got our information,
        ;; get it to the user ASAP.
        (when (eldoc-display-message-p)
          (eldoc-message (slime-autodoc--format doc multilinep))))))

  (advice-add 'slime-autodoc--async% :override #'slime-autodoc--async%-fixed))
```

The above will fix the freezing when moving around when connected to a SWANK server, if you want to fix all instances of the bug you'll need to override a couple more functions:

```
;; fix for slime <v2.21 in emacs 26 (eldoc-message now only takes 1 arg)
(when (version< slime-version "2.21")
  (defun slime-autodoc--async%-fixed (context multilinep doc)
    (cl-destructuring-bind (doc cache-p) doc
      (unless (eq doc :not-available)
        (when cache-p
          (slime-autodoc--cache-put context doc))
        ;; Now that we've got our information,
        ;; get it to the user ASAP.
        (when (eldoc-display-message-p)
          (eldoc-message (slime-autodoc--format doc multilinep))))))

  (defun slime-autodoc-manually-fixed ()
    "Like autodoc informtion forcing multiline display."
    (interactive)
    (let ((doc (slime-autodoc t)))
      (cond (doc (eldoc-message doc))
        (t (eldoc-message nil)))))

  (defun slime-autodoc-space-fixed (n)
    "Like `slime-space' but nicer."
    (interactive "p")
    (self-insert-command n)
    (let ((doc (slime-autodoc)))
      (when doc
    (eldoc-message doc))))

  (advice-add 'slime-autodoc--async% :override #'slime-autodoc--async%-fixed)
  (advice-add 'slime-autodoc-manually :override #'slime-autodoc-manually-fixed)
  (advice-add 'slime-autodoc-space :override #'slime-autodoc-space-fixed))
```

Answer (score 2):

For part one of this question the answer is no I was not barking up the wrong tree.  To understand a little of why I have assembled my notes below.

SLIME did indeed had an issue with eldoc.

Eldoc changed it's documentation methods as described in [the emacs NEWS file](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.26).  [This bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27230) sheds some more light on it.

Slime did indeed violate the new contract as documented [here](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/406),[here](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/400), and most importantly for me [here](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/450).  The key phrase being

> Now that Emacs 26.1 is out it would be nice to make a new release available via quicklisp.

I'm not certain about it but a quick check says I'm at the latest and greatest quicklisp.

```
; SLIME 2.21
CL-USER> (ql:update-dist "quicklisp")
You already have the latest version of "quicklisp": 2018-04-30.
NIL
CL-USER> (ql:update-client)
The most up-to-date client, version 2017-03-06, is already installed.
T
```

So after my latest update of slime from package mode I now have SLIME at:

```
slime              20180630.1721
```

Which means I'm running swank and slime somewhat apart from generating this error:

```
Versions differ: 2.21 (slime) vs. 2.20 (swank). Continue? (y or n) y
```

But I can live with that over endless pauses for errors to bubble up into the UI.

Hope this helps someone else.